# Issues with only using conduit for receptacles and lights in new workshop instead of in-wall cable?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

I'm trying to make this structure as weather and rodent/insect-proof as possible so ideally, I don't want any holes in the walls and ceilings. I know in my current shop I'm always running new outlets as I move equipment around so I had this idea of not running NM cable in the walls but instead running a couple of 1" conduit runs around the ceilings and doing drops to outlets where I need them. Same with lights. Since the walls are high the conduit won't get in the way and this would allow me to branch off a new outlet anywhere in the shop while also not having holes in the walls. I would put a junction box every 6' so I could easily branch off when the time comes.
Are there any issues, besides it costing more, with this approach?

Comment: For things you're less likely to change (in the wanting to pull more wires in way, anyway), that are single drops, armored flex cable can be handy (lights, for instance.)

Answer (score 4):

This is a great idea. It also:

- Eliminates the need for separate ground wires (assuming you use metal conduit)
- Allows for upgrades. Want to install a heavy-duty tool that needs 30A instead of 20A? No problem - just add (or replace) wires in the conduit.

Keep in mind that there are limits to conduit, such that if you hit a certain limit (I think 4 circuits, but not sure) that you have to *derate*, which then leads to bigger wires and other problems.

Comment: 4 circuits is all you want to put into conduit.  Above that (or above 30A) you'll have to fiddle with derates a lot.

Comment: Any conduit? So, if I ran 2" I would still only want four circuits? If that's the case I'm better off running 2- 3/4" conduits on each side

Comment: Correct. There is an exception for very short conduit (IIRC, such as up to 24" connecting a panel to a subpanel) but for normal use, the # of circuits really affects things. Keep in mind though (Harper can clarify) a circuit could be 240V/MWBC.

Comment: @RyanDetzel... yeah unfortunately.  The rules improve for 2-1/2" and above, but prices get worse.  My own preference is for 1/2" conduit since it accepts 9-10 wires up to #12, so four 20A circuits and 1-2 of them can be 3-wire H-H-N.  Assuming you are using shell as ground.  I'm a big fan of multiple parallel conduits.